# Read File and display contents

Tags: c#, file-io

I want that when I click the button "List all Customers", the code should read the Customer.csv file and display the information on the form called "List All Customers".

How can I do that?

```
public static void ReadFile()
{
    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("Customer.csv");
}

public static void LoadCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists("Customer.csv"))
        {
            string temp = null;
            int count = 0;

            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"Customer.csv"))
            {
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.Trim();
                    string[] lineHolder = temp.Split(',');
                    Customer tempCust = new Customer();
                    tempCust.customerName = lineHolder[0];
                    tempCust.customerAddress = lineHolder[1];
                    tempCust.customerZip = Convert.ToInt32(lineHolder[2]);
                    myCustArray[count] = tempCust;
                    count++;
                }//end for loop
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create("Customer.csv");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File Loading Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of control you want to display this data in but your method could just return a list of `Customer`, then you can add to a `ListBox`, `ListView` or `DataGrid`

```
public static IEnumerable<Customer> LoadCustomers(string filename)
{
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename).Where(l => l.Contains(',')))
        {
            var splitLine = line.Split(',');
            if (splitLine.Count() >= 3)
            {
                yield return new Customer
                {
                    customerName = splitLine[0].Trim(),
                    customerAddress = splitLine[1].Trim(),
                    customerZip = Convert.ToInt32(splitLine[2].Trim())
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ListBox

```
 listBox1.DisplayMember = "customerName";
 listBox1.Items.AddRange(LoadCustomers(@"G:\Customers.csv").ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take advantage of the list object:

```
public static void ReadFile()
{
    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("Customer.csv");
}

public static void LoadCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists("Customer.csv"))
        {
            string temp = null;
            var retList = new List<Customer>();
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"Customer.csv"))
            {
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp = temp.Trim();
                    string[] lineHolder = temp.Split(',');
                    retlist.add(new Customer(){
                      customerName = linerHolder[0],
                      customerAddress = lineHolder[1],
                      customerZip = Convert.ToInt32(lineHolder[2])
                    });
                }//end for loop
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create("Customer.csv");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File Loading Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

just wrap it up in a class, call if from the controller and populate up the results.  Depending on how often you will be updating this data, you might look into caching it, so you don't have to run this process every X seconds for each user.